# Get only certain Strings from plist iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have a plist and I want ot grab only the items which 'Name' string begins with 'A'.  I want then display these in my UITableView, along with the 'NameOrigin' included in the item.  I have included a screen shot of my plist.  Thanks

[image]

My code so far, I am able to display all of the plist items, but I would like to filter the items displayed to ones with string 'Name' being with the letter 'A'?

```
-(NSArray *)content
{
    //if (!_content) {
    _content = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"MyPLIST" ofType:@"plist"]];
    // }
    return _content;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [TableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"NameOrigin"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? So far you've only stated what you want to do. Update your question with the relevant code you have for loading the plist file and getting the desired data out it. Explain what issues you are having with the code.

Comment: 1) Why did you comment out the `if` statement in your `content` method? You need that. 2) Update the `content` method so that when you load the plist, you filter the list with just the values you need.

Comment: How do i filter just the content i need?

Comment: Loop through the data and create a new array with matching values.

Comment: -(NSArray *)content
{
    if (!_content) {
    _content = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"MyPLIST" ofType:@"plist"]];
     }
    
   NSString *nameFirstLetter = @"A";
    
    for (NSDictionary *name in self.content) {
        NSString *currentName = (NSString *)[name objectForKey:@"Name"];
        
        if ([currentName substringToIndex:1] == nameFirstLetter) {
            [self.nameByLetter addObject:currentName];
        }
    }
    
    return _nameByLetter;
}

Comment: something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter for only elements where `Name` begins with "A", try this:

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [self.content filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name beginswith %@", @"A"]];
```

While we're at it: you should consider refactoring your code a bit. Re-loading the data from file *every time* you call `[self content]` is a *bad* idea, performance wise. Instead try this:

```
// Create a property called content in your class extension on the top of the .m file of your table view controller
@interface YourTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *content;
@end
```

Next, add this code in your `viewDidLoad` callback:

```
_content = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyPLIST" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

and delete the custom `content` method.

Comment: Thank you, i'm not sure where to put or how the predicate works? Does it automatically know to filter out the first letter of each string?

Comment: A predicate is a way to describe a search. In your case, the `NSDictionary` objects inside your `contents` array that is read from the *plist* file all have a `Name` key, so you could say `[[self.content objectAtIndex: 0] valueForKey:@"Name"]`. Instead of writing a loop and testing every single dictionary object, the NSPredicate is a shortcut with the same effect.

Comment: What this particular predicate does is to find all the dictionary objects in `self.contents` that have a value for the key `Name` that begins with the letter **A**.